# wordpress drop down menu outside fixed header div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm struggling with some css.

I have an dropdown menu made with javascript. The dropdown works fine but when I press the button, the fixed header on top of the page will expand.

What I want is that when I press the button the dropdown menu will be visable outside the fixed header div.

```js
( function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' ), button, menu;
    if ( ! nav ) {
        return;
    }
 
    button = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    menu   = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
    if ( ! button ) {
        return;
    }
 
    // Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
    if ( ! menu || ! menu.childNodes.length ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }
 
  button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
            menu.className = 'nav-menu';
   alert('hallo');
        }
 
        if ( -1 !== button.className.indexOf( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
            button.className = button.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
            menu.className = menu.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
   alert('replace toggled-on');
        } else {
            button.className += ' toggled-on';
            menu.className += ' toggled-on';
   alert('+= toggled-on');
        }
    };
} )(jQuery);
```

```css
/* Navigation Menu */
.main-navigation {
 position: relative;
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 
 
}

.menu-hoofd-menu-container {
 height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;  
    left: -30px; top: 0px;  
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-menu {
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px;
 z-index: 999;
}

.main-navigation li {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 0.857142857rem;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.main-navigation a {
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.main-navigation a:hover,
.main-navigation a:focus {
    color: #21759b;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    display: none;
}
 
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on,
.menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-content">
   <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ); ?>" alt="logo" />
   
   <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle">Menu</button>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
   </nav>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be acheived by using the css below:

```
nav#site-navigation.main-navigation{
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can then adjust it's position by adding values for `left` and `top` etc, see below example

```
nav#site-navigation.main-navigation{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}
```

This places the open menu at the top left, you can substitute those values as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your overflow is set to hidden.  Change that to visible.